# devexpress callback results syntax

Tags: javascript, asp.net, datagridview, callback, devexpress

I am trying to figure out the correct javascript syntax for a DevExpress datagrid callback to pass data back to the client.

In the .aspx I installed an onclick event in the DataGrid row with a CustomCallback event using the js call: `dg.PerformCallback(key);` and in the aspx.cs file this function is correctly reached, however I cannot pass data back to the client:

```
protected void dg_CustomCallback(
   object sender, 
   DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridViewCustomCallbackEventArgs e)
{
    string key = e.Parameters; // works
    e.Results = "something"; // .Results does not exist        
    return;
}
```

Then I switched from a CustomCallback to a DataCallback because the `DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridViewCustomDataCallbackEventArgs` does have a `.Results` property. However, I cannot figure out the corresponding javascript call. I tried in vain: `dg.PerformCallback(key);` , `dg.PerformDataCallback(key);` and `dg.SendCallback(key);`

Also I am wondering, when the above problem is fixed, which js function I need to program to receive the return data from the server after the callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve can be done using the `JSProperties` on callback and the OnEndCallback client side event of the **ASPxGridview**. This aspx tag can be placed exactly after the `</Columns>` closing tag of the **ASPxGridview**.

```
<ClientSideEvents EndCallback="function(s,e)
{
   var errText = s.cpError;
   if (errText != "")
     {
         alert(errText);
     }
}" />
```

On the server side you set the JSProperties like this

```
gridOfApp.JSProperties["cpError"] = "The error was major!";
```

Important. Bear in mind that your JSProperties MUST ALWAYS start with the cp prefix.

Comment: @ Thanos K: Thanks for your help. I will certainly try this sometime, but for now I realized that in this case I can avoid the callback altogether, as what I need is to highlight the row(s) that the user selects, which can be done using just some client side js code. Collecting the set of selected row key values to be transmitted when the user clicks the OK button is also a client side js task.